# C# HttpWebrequest with CredentialCache succeeds from Windows but fails from Ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, httpwebrequest

I have some (fairly ugly, but functional) C# code that I use to retrieve files from web sites. These web sites are varied between secured and unsecured sites, and the files vary in types (some are images, some are compressed files, etc).

I have created a CredentialCache with the various authentication information for these web sites, and I set this into the HttpWebRequest.Credentials member.

The code is targeting V2.0 of the .NET framework.

When I compile and run this code under Windows, using Visual Studio 17 Community edition, it works perfectly. Any file I attempt to retrieve is retrieved without problem, regardless of whether it requires authentication.

When I load the same project into MonoDevelop under Ubuntu, it compiles fine, and runs without problem. However, it will only retrieve files which do not require authentication. Any file that requires authentication returns a 401 - Not Authenticated response.

I am using the same CredentialCache in both instances (I persisted the CredentialCache to disk and reload it each time the program is run - to avoid having to type in all the varied credentials each time.)

I would appreciate any pointers on why this is failing... I can post code sections if that will help....

Comment: It is better to add code, and the url for the page you are failed to download.

Comment: Can't post the links - they are not publicly accessible. I'll cut down the code to a "minimal" demonstration subset and post that as soon as I have a few minutes.

Comment: Well, I cut down the code to demonstrate the problem, and darned if the simplified code isn't working. So apparently I'm doing something stupid somewhere. So... Thanks anyway.